# Algorithm to move sprite given an offset

Tags: algorithm

I would like to move a sprite across the screen in relation to the input offset the system gives me. I've figured out where the sprite should be, but what is a function which will give the desired output, given the input? Here's the input and output:

```
   0 -> -160
-120 -> -200
-240 -> -240
-360 -> -280
-480 -> -320
```

0 is the max, -480 the min, and -240 corresponds exactly, but the system will interpolate other input positions. Hence the need for a function with an algorithm to determine the output given the input, and not a lookup table.

This should be pretty easy, but I am stupid.

Comment: Can't understand your question..

Comment: If the system asks me to draw the sprite at pixel offset 0, I would like to draw it at offset -160. If it asks for -240, then I would draw at -240. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-)

```
position = -160 + (input/3)
```

that should do the trick

Comment: 3: it's the magic number. Did you just eyeball it or can you derive 3 from the other numbers, like the step of 120?

Comment: it is derived from other numbers -120 -> give -40 delta , -240 gives -80 delta ...., so yes I use step of 120 to figure gain proportion